# Convert string to number in power bi

Tags: type-conversion, powerbi

I'm using Power BI and was wondering how I would create a new column that converts any row that is "Processed" in my Status column, to be represented by a 1 in the new column?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use an `IF` function.

```
NewColumn = IF(Table1[Status] = "Processed", 1, 0)
```

This returns `1` if the `Status` is "Processed" and `0` otherwise.